# Final index being sent in request loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am polling an API and creating a list of json data.

I am iterating over it and anything that is a new record is being sent to a different API. This is working well except that the last index in the list is being sent even though it is identical to what was sent before.

It is as if the check I have written is not being applied to the final record.

```
def send_to_api():
    # we are now going to send each entry in our live_alarms list to     api
    data = alert
    data_json = json.dumps(data)
    requests.get('https://webhook.site/f', json=data_json)  # ( 5)   using for testing

def update_and_send_live_alarms():
    global alert
    for alert in alarms:                        # (1)
        global live_alarms
        if alert not in live_alarms:            # (2)
            if any(d.get('tinyId', None) == alert['tinyId'] for d in live_alarms):      
                live_alarms = [i for i in live_alarms if not (i['tinyId']== alert['tinyId'])]
                send_to_api()               # (5)
                live_alarms.append(alert)       # (6)
            else:
                send_to_api()
                live_alarms.append(alert)       # (6)


def main():
    # here we complete all functions every 5 minuets
    while True:
        global live_alarms
        global alarms
        print(live_alarms)
        alarms = (get_alarms())
        update_and_send_live_alarms()
        send_to_avantio()
        time.sleep(30)
        print(live_alarms)

# variables
live_alarms = []

main()
```

Comment: I have added an item to the list that will stay as the final entry through the process.
The idea being i can write a check for this and only send if it is not it.
However it seems that it is not just sending the last entry as when i run after making this change it will send the last but one entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling send_to_api() by itself in the main() of my code.
Nothing to see here........